# Creating a cloud page and there is unaccounted for padding between my divs - how to remove?

Tags: marketing-cloud, css, html, cloudpage

I'm using a combination of hard-coding (top div) and content blocks (bottom div) on my page. When they render, there is a space between them (see image). I would like them to just directly stack on top of each other. Does anyone have any pointers? Code below. In this image I've shared, the red rectangle shows that there is a stripe of non-light grey (top div) and non-white (bottom div) and I want to get rid of that.

[image: The white area within the red rectangle shouldn't be there.]

```
<div class="cta-primary" style="background-image: url('https://image.email.edgepark.com/lib/fe6915707165057f711d/m/7/38ff2d91-174d-4090-84d0-b4662ac3b7f2.png'); background-size: 300px; background-position: right; background-color: #e6e6e6; margin-bottom: 0px !important; ">
  <h1 style="font-weight:300;">
    Get the InPen&trade; through Insurance
  </h1>
  <h3 style="font-weight: 300;">
    Edgepark has the expertise to help you get an <br> InPen&trade; Smart Insulin Pen through insurance.
  </h3>
</div>
<div class="layout layout-canvas-g" style="padding-top: 0px !important; margin-top: 0px !important">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="columns col1">
      <div data-type="slot" data-key="col1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try creating the same page using just HTML and the Classic editor. The new one tends to add stuff on it’s own. As an alternative, you could also try changing the CloudPage’s background color to grey in the code view of the actual CloudPage (not the content block), maybe that would help

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved some weirdness (coming from customer CSS without proper resets) using this line in the CP's styles:

```
*::after, *::before { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

You can read up on that here if you want: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Other than that, it's pretty hard to tell where the spacing is coming from without access to your site and/or the complete rendered HMTL.